# Is this the best way to update all documents in a Firestore collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

There are similar questions and answers out there, but none that seem concerned about concurrency or using transactions when iterating over the entire collection.

To ensure that I'm not reading one version of a document, updating it, then clobbering some change that happened since the read, I'd like to use transactions.

Firestore transactions are limited to 500 updates.

My approach is to use pagination, getting 500 document references at a time.
Then use those refs with `getAll` within a transaction to guarantee no concurrent modification can happen.

Is it OK/wise to pass 500 refs to getAll like this?
Is this approach efficient, from a performance and cost perspective?

Pseudo-code (TypeScript-like)

```js
  const pageSize = 500;
  let lastSnapshot = null;
  let count = 0;
  do {
    // Get up to 500 (pageSize) document references
    let query = firestore.collection('myCollection').limit(pageSize);
    if (lastSnapshot) {
      myDataQuery = myDataQuery.startAfter(lastSnapshot);
    }
    const snapshots = await playerPlotQuery.get();
    const refs = snapshots.docs.map(d => d.ref);
    // Start a transaction
    await firestore.runTransaction(async transaction => {
      // Get all the documents again, this time in a transaction
      const snapshots = await transaction.getAll(...refs);
      for (const snapshot of snapshots) {
        // Perform some update on each document
        transaction.update(snapshot.ref,{someField: 0, anotherField: "foo"});
      }
    });
  } while (refs.length === pageSize);
```

Comment: It's worth noting that even with this paginated transactional approach, if the applications and servers using Firestore add new documents while this is running, they may be added _behind_ the cursor, and not updated.  To avoid that would require downtime or some other sort of lock-out.  Or change the other code first, then migrate older documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are making use of [`Transaction#getAll()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html#getAll), I'm going to assume you are using the Node client for Firestore. This means you have access to [`Transaction#get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Transaction#get) and can execute the query directly inside the transaction. This change alone cuts your document reads in half because you are no longer checking them twice.

```js
const pageSize = 500;
const baseQuery = db.collection('myCollection').limit(pageSize); // highly recommend using orderBy here on something like a 'creationTime' property
let totalCount = 0, pageCount = 0;
do {
  const pageQuery = lastSnapshot ? baseQuery.startAfter(lastSnapshot) : baseQuery;

  totalCount += pageCount = await db.runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
    const querySnapshot = await transaction.get(pageQuery);
    querySnapshot.forEach(docSnap => {
      transaction.update(docSnap.ref, { someField: 0, anotherField: "foo" });
      lastSnapshot = docSnap;
    });
    return querySnapshot.size; // return the page count inside the runTransaction's Promise
  });
} while (pageCount === pageSize);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know I could initiate the query outside the transaction and use it within like this.  (`querySnapshot.size` is not a function; doesn't need parenthesis)